# What is the value of $x$ in the logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$\log_2 24 - \log_2 3= \log_2 x$?

Comment: What properties of logarithms do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_2 24- \log_2 3=\log_2 x \implies \log_2 (24/3)=\log_2 8=\log_2 x \implies x=8$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions for which an attempt has not been made.

Comment: @dr zafar ahmed DSc, thank you